Autorun script in Raspberry Pi 4
I am trying to autorun my Python script whenever my Raspberry Pi 4 boots up or when I start connecting it to a power source, but I already tried different methods but didn't work.
By the way, my Python script is about image processing, where it will open the raspberry pi camera for pothole detection.
I already tried the -cron method and put this code inside but it didn't work:
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/raspberrypi/tflite-custom-object-bookworm-main/d>
Tried using rc.local and didn't work as well:
/usr/bin/python3 /home/raspberrypi/tflite-custom-object-bookworm-main/detect1.p>
Tried LXSession on my .config and placed this code on my autostart file but didn't work:
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
point-rpi
@lxterminal -e sudo python3 /home/raspberrypi/Desktop/detect1.py

Done doing the systemd method as well and it didn't work. Here's the code I used:
[Unit]
Description=My Auto-start Service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/your/script.sh
WorkingDirectory=/path/to
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
User=raspberrypi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

So far, when I reboot my raspberry pi, the script is not auto running, I need to open the terminal first before the script autorun. Please help! Thank you in advance!

Different OS and versions use different methods to get things started at boot. Which OS are you using?  I have a Raspi 4B running Raspian OS lite Bookworm and I was able to get my python script to auto-start on boot working with crontab using this example: https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/ Here are the exact commands I used:
Create a startup script:
sudo nano start_on_power_on.sh

File contents below. Username is your current login username and assumes your file is located at your /home/Username directory.  "main_loop.py" is the python filename:
cd /
cd home/Username
sudo python main_loop.py
cd /

Hit CTRL+X then Y to save to file.
Then make .sh file executable:
sudo chmod 755 start_on_power_on.sh

Prepare log file directory:
sudo mkdir logs

Edit crontab
sudo crontab -e

Add this line below the comments:
@reboot sh /start_on_power_on.sh >/home/Username/logs/cronlog 2>&1

At first it wasn't working, so I reviewed the log file located here: /home/Username/logs/cronlog by issuing:
cd /logs
cat cronlog

I learned from bash reported errors that my directories were off a bit, so I made some adjustments and the corrected directories are included above.  Running again I learned my Python code ran into new errors because things that depended on the internet were failing because the network and TCP/IP was not available yet.  So after multiple rounds of reviewing the cronlog, code updates, and sudo reboots I was able to get my python code to run at startup successfully.
You can also see if your script is running by issuing a command similar to this:
ps ax | grep python

And you should get a response something like this:
532 ?        S      0:00 sudo python main_loop.py
548 ?        S      0:02 python main_loop.py
970 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto python

